# Trying to plot a CSV file that contains latitude and longitude values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, netcdf

I first downloaded NetCDF4 data from this [website](https://daac.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/M2I1NXLFO_5.12.4/summary?keywords=M2I1NXLFO). Now, I wanted to make the file more cloud friendly so I converted it into CSV. After that, my rows and columns in the CSV looked like this.

[image]

Now, I want to make a plot which will plot an image which will be similar to the earth plot in this [link](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/information/howto?title=How%20to%20read%20and%20plot%20NetCDF%20MERRA-2%20data%20in%20Python). The only difference is that they are plotting the plot directly from the netCDF4 file without converting it into CSV but I am trying to plot it after converting to CSV. I want to show the TLML values in the Earth plot.

If anyone is interested, this is how I converted my netCDF4 file into CSV.

```
import xarray as xr

file = "C:/Users/xyz/plotting-try/MERRA2_400.inst1_2d_lfo_Nx.20220203.nc4"

nc = xr.open_dataset(file)
nc.TLML[1,:,:].to_dataframe().to_csv('T2M.csv')
```

Can anyone help me on the plotting part? As mentioned, I want to plot it similar to how it was shown in the above link, just that I want to plot it using my CSV file.

If you want to download the netCDF4 file on your system, you can download it [here](https://goldsmr4.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/MERRA2/M2I1NXLFO.5.12.4/2022/02/MERRA2_400.inst1_2d_lfo_Nx.20220203.nc4). However, you'll first need to create an account on the Nasa [website](https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/profile).

**Edit:** I have tried the below code but it isn't working.

```
df = pd.read_csv('T2M.csv')

lat = df['lat']
lon = df['lon']
time = df['time']
T2M = df['TLML']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines(resolution="110m",linewidth=1)
ax.gridlines(linestyle='--',color='black')

clevs = np.arange(576,361,24)
plt.contourf(lon, lat, T2M, clevs, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap=plt.cm.jet)

plt.title('MERRA-2 Air Temperature at 2m, January 2010', size=14)
cb = plt.colorbar(ax=ax, orientation="vertical", pad=0.02, aspect=16, shrink=0.8)
cb.set_label('K',size=12,rotation=0,labelpad=15)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)

fig.savefig('MERRA2_t2m.png', format='png', dpi=360)
```

This throws an error that `TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 1D`. And it throws on this line: `plt.contourf(lon, lat, T2M, clevs, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap=plt.cm.jet)`

I'm not even sure whether the conversion into CSV format is done correctly. Anyone who has an experience working with these kind of files, please help me on this.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so far...

Comment: Added what I've tried.

Comment: Try tricontourf if your data is ungridded.

Answer (score 0):

I can't download the file, but I have a sugestion that seens that will work.

The columns `lat` and `lon` are not pivoted. Because this there are a lot of values repeating in one column for different values of the another column. You have to separate and convert your data.

First of all, I suggest using the `pandas`(https://pandas.pydata.org/) library that is very good to read `csv` files and make transformations on your data.

Your data will be stored in a `DataFrame` that is a `pandas` object that present similarities with a table. The `lat` and `lon` will be converted to unique values and the table will be pivoted to create the 2d table, for each `lat`(row) and for each `lon`(column) we will have only one `T2M`.

The code will be like this:

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'some_path/file_name.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)

lat = df['lat'].unique()
len = df['lat'].unique()
T2M = df.pivot(index='lat', columns='len', values='TLML')
```

Now your `T2M` variable will have 2 dimensions.